# OMNET++ connecting custome Wireless Node module to wlan

Tags: omnet++

I'm relatively new to OMNET++ and INET and would like to connect a submodule that I have created to measure wireless fingerprint called fingerPrinter to the wlan gate, but I get the following error during runtime:

*(omnetpp::cGate)NetworkA.hostA.wlan[1].upperLayerOut: connectTo(): Gate already connected*

Here is my .ned file:

```
import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;
import inet.environment.common.PhysicalEnvironment;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.contract.IIntegratedVisualizer;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.node.aodv.AODVRouter;
import inet.applications.udpapp.UDPBasicApp;
//import inet.physicallayer.common.bitlevel.SignalSampleModel;

simple FingerPrinter
{
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}

module WHost extends AODVRouter
{
    parameters:
        @networkNode;
        @labels(wireless-node);
    submodules:
        fingerPrinter: FingerPrinter {
            @display("p=429,125");
        }
    //        signal: SignalSampleModel;
    connections:
        //fingerPrinter.in <-- networkLayer.transportOut++;
        //fingerPrinter.out --> networkLayer.transportIn++;
        wlan[1].upperLayerOut --> fingerPrinter.in;
}


network NetworkA
{
    parameters:
        string hostType = default("AODVRouter");
        string mediumType = default("Ieee80211Radio");
        string pathLossType = default("TwoRayGroundReflection");
        @display("bgb=100,100;bgg=100,1,grey95");
    submodules:
        physicalEnvironment: PhysicalEnvironment {
            @display("p=110,0");
        }
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=110,33.33");
        }
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            @display("p=110,66.66");
        }
        visualizer: <default("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer")> like IIntegratedVisualizer if hasVisualizer() {
            @display("p=110,100");
        }
        AP1: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=0,0");
        }
        AP2: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=100,0");
        }
        AP3: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=0,100");
        }
        AP4: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=100,100");
        }
        hostA: WHost {
            @display("p=50,50");
        }

}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because your `WHost` inherits from `AODVRoouter` which inherits from `WirelessHost` which inherits from `StandardHost` which imherits from `NodeBase`. In NodeBase.ned INET have that gate already connected to the networkLayer:

```
for i=0..sizeof(radioIn)-1 {
    radioIn[i] --> { @display("m=s"); } --> wlan[i].radioIn;
    wlan[i].upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.ifIn++;
    wlan[i].upperLayerIn <-- networkLayer.ifOut++;
}
```

and you cannot remove a connection between modules when you are using inheritance (unless the code was especially written for that function).

Depending on what you want to achieve you have 3 options:

- The IP module in INET has netfilter hooks, i.e. you can install code fragments that are notified whenever something is received from the below layer. You can do various things with that. This facility is mostly used by routing protocols to monitor the traffic and modify the routing table accordingly.
- You can copy the whole inheritance chain i.e. make a copy of `NodeBase`, `StandardHost`, etc. with a different typename and put your new module in the alternative NodeBase code between the network layer and the WLAN card. This is ugly and it's what mostly happens when inheritance is used instead of composition.
- And the recommended way: INET was designed is a way that the Network Interfaces should be replaceable. You can create a compound module that implements `IWirelessNic`, put your module and an `Ieee80211Nic` inside, connect them accordingly and configure that interface type to be used instead of the default `Ieee80211Nic`. This essentially means that you have created a new WiFi card, that contains your own code and then inserted that new card into your host.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But since I'm new as I said, I don't know how I can configure my custom Wireless module to be used as default. Could you please help?